# How to decode the following code in Json?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode the following JSON using php json_decode function.

[{"total_count":17}]

I think the square brackets in output is preventing it. How do I get around that? I can't control the output because it is coming from Facebook FQL query:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.apple.com%22

Comment: It's an array with a single object, with one key/value pair.

Comment: The above string is valid for json, i dun understand why you can't do the decode. You might need to include your code for decode

Comment: What is your error/output? It decodes correctly for me.

Comment: Is the problem decoding it or using it? Did you keep in mind that the result is an array?

Comment: I forgot that the result was an array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns an instance of stdClass by default.

For you, it's probably easier to deal with array. You can force PHP to return arrays, as a second parameter to json_decode:

```
$var = json_decode('[{"total_count":17}]', true);
```

After that, you can access the variable as `$result[0]['total_count']`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that the result was an array. I was missing the true there.

Answer (score 0):

See this JS fiddle for an example of how to read it:

http://jsfiddle.net/8V4qP/1

It's basically the same code for PHP, except you need to pass true as your second argument to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to tell php you want to use it as associative arrays instead of actual objects:

```
<?php
    $result = json_decode('[{"total_count":17}]', true);
    print $result[0]['total_count'];
?>
```

if you don't pass true, you would have to access it like this: `$result[0]->total_count` because it is an array containing an object, not an array containing an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = "[{\"total_count\":17}]";

$arr = Jason_decode($json);
foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    echo $obj->total_count . "<br>";
}
```

Or use `json_decode($json, true)` if you want associative arrays instead of objects.